# jQuery plugin to animate colors from one class to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colors, jquery-animate

There are a lot of jQuery color plugins.
However I couldn't find the one to animate between css class declarations.

For example doing a smooth animation from `.class1` to `.class2`:

```
.class1 { background-color: #000000 }
.class2 { background-color: #000088 }
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery [`animate()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) command already allows you to animate colour transitions.

Here's a [more striking demo](http://jsbin.com/uqoji)

**EDIT:**

To get the same effect with CSS classes, there is

- jQuery UI's [`switchClass(add, remove, duration)`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/)
- Igor Vieira's [`animateToClass plugin`](http://igorvieira.com/blog/animate-to-class-en)
- James Padolsey's [`animateToSelector plugin`](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/animateToSelector/)

Comment: see updated answer. IIRC, switchClass is somewhat temperamental and doesn't work at all in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I think a plugin can be done that will read all computed properties of class A, match them with the properties of class B, animate what it can be animated, and ignore the rest of properties.

I have not seen no one out there but it can be done.

Comment: I've had some lag, is before coffee :)