# Find Hover CSS Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

Lets say I had an element with multiple classes, one of these classes has a hover pseudo-class. Lets say this will change the colour.

So what I want to do is find out what colour the element will change to when hovered over. Then I want to override this with Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: why do you want to find out the color if you're just going to override it?

Comment: I thought about animating it with jQuery instead of it being an instant change. Also I'm curious to find out if it's possible.

Comment: @Ben - you can find out the css style of a certain class, so if the class is named hover then yes you can find out the color style, refer to this for help: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

Comment: @TStamper: But not for pseudo-classes?

Comment: @Ben- you probably can, but im not sure, but why not just change the fact that its a pseudo class into an actual class?

Comment: @TStamper: I wanted to make it into a plugin so I wouldn't have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The [animateToSelector jQuery plug-in](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/animateToSelector/) seems to do what you want.

I found that plug-in through [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592990/jquery-plugin-to-animate-colors-form-one-class-to-another/1593025#1593025). Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript) to see there isn't really any other way to do it but by going through `document.styleSheets`.